# insert string from textarea having comma same like csv using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

inserting data from csv containing comma in name is working fine . that inserts same as i want e.g "test,name"

i am inserting data into database from a text area. using this code

```
 $addmult = nl2br($_POST['textarea']);        
    $data1 = explode('<br />',$addmult);    
    foreach($data1 as $dataline)
                {
                    $line   = explode(',',$dataline);
                    $name   = $line[0];
                    $partno = $line[1];
                    $detail = $line[2];
                    $qty    = $line[3];
                    $price  = $line[4];
    $sql = "insert into tablename set name=$name, partno=$partno, detail=$detail, qty=$qty, price=$price";

}
```

it's working, but what if i want to insert the "name" having comma in it. 
for example i wnant to insert this data (name="test,name")

```
test,name,123,testdetails,2,100
test,name2,321,testdetails2,22,200
```

the code above will split the name but i wnat name as "test,name" and "test,name2"

thanks

Comment: Unless you enforce some sort of quoting, there is no way to determine where the split should be.  Either you need to quote your name or use a different way of splitting values.

Comment: Try using extract() http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php which automatically convert array to variable.

Comment: @AleksG thanks. for your comment. when i use a csv file containing comma in name. that is saved exactly how i want. "test,name"

Comment: @Ali can you give me some sample code or example

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: why then dont try separating with something else, like ";" for each field, so you can use the , in the middoe lf a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will str_getcsv() work for you? It will parse a CSV string into an array...

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

The following:

```
<?php
    $stringAry = "\"test,name\",123,testdetails,2,100";
    print_r(str_getcsv($stringAry));
?>
```

Note, `"test,name"` is surrounded by quotes in the CSV line, otherwise it is two columns and not one.

Outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => test,name
    [1] => 123
    [2] => testdetails
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 100
)
```

So you could do something like

```
<?php
    $stringAry = "\"test,name\",123,testdetails,2,100";
    $sql = "insert into tablename set name={stringAry[0]}, partno={stringAry[1]}, detail={stringAry[2]}, qty=$qty, price={stringAry[3]}";
?>
```

If the user forgets to quote the name or the details you could figure out that you have more columns that you should and combine all adjacent non-numeric columns seeing as you only have two non-numeric columns and they are separated by a numeric column.

Also, I know the above is an example so you probably have considered this, but just in case: consider using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for user input, or the equivalent for the DB you're using...

Comment: Thanke for your reply . this is gonna work for me . but having a little problem with this.

the above code do exactly what i want. but wehn i enter the same string in text area and process it, then it doesn't work.

Comment: when i enter "test,name",123,testdetail,2,100 in text area this is not woking like the above string in your example

Comment: the difference is may be in the the commas you i code in string and in text area

Answer (score 0):

This is such a poorly worded question, I can't really tell what you are asking. I assume you want to take input from a textarea and split it up based on commas - if one of the values has a comma in it, it treats it as two fields.

As the comments suggest, you could escape it, or, even simply, replace ',' in your input. E.g.

```
$input = $_POST['input'];

$replacedInput = str_replace(',', '-', $input);
```

NOTE: This will replce ',' with '-' in your input. You could then pick this character up the other end when outputting so that it replaces '-' with ',' - or a less used character. This code is not tested.

After reading your question again, you need something like this:

```
 $sql = "insert into tablename set name='".$name."', partno='".$partno."', detail='".$detail."', qty='".$qty."', price='".$price."'";
```

Comment: thanks. you understood exactly what i wanted to ask. then how can you say that this is poorly worded question.

Comment: Sorry. No offence intended - It was just an awkward question to answer. If this has helped you, mark it as helpful.

Comment: this was clearly not helpful. and i have marked another answer .